# Assignment of escape sequence in character array using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, character, newline

I need to modify a character array, including new line ('\n'), such that when I print the char array, it should print the elements as they are formatted.

I don't know how it works when I remove those comments inside the loops, and why not it works in foreach loop.

Can anyone help me here???

```
     int row, col;
     row = col = 2;
     int j;
     char[] ch = new char[ row * col + row ];
     for( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) {
        for( j = 0; j < 2; j++ ) {
           ch[ i * col + j ] = 'a';
           //Console.Write(ch[ i * col + j ]);
        }
        ch[ i * col + j ] = '\n';
        //Console.Write(ch[ i * col + j ]);
     }
     Console.WriteLine("Character Array:");
     foreach( char c in ch ) {
        Console.Write(c);
     }
```

my output should be as:

```
    aa
    aa
```

Comment: Could you also post how your current output looks like?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? (why are you using i*col ).

Comment: @Nikita I'm Storing 2D representation in single dimensional array. But that's not the issue. Problem is my new line in the character array is not working in foreach loop and Console.Write(ch)

Comment: @PhillipD
(comments removed)
     aa<newline>
     aa
     Character Array:
     aaaa
     <newline>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you overwrite your "\n", you need to reserve one additional column for the \n character.
This worked for me:

```
int row, col;
row = col = 2;
col = 2;
int j;
char[] ch = new char[ row * (col+1) ];
for( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) {
    for( j = 0; j < 2; j++ ) {
        ch[ i * (col+1) + j ] = 'a';
        //Console.Write(ch[ i * col + j ]);
     }
     ch[ i * (col+1) + j ] = '\n';
     //Console.Write(ch[ i * col + j ]);
}
Console.WriteLine("Character Array:");
foreach( char c in ch ) {
    Console.Write(c);
}
```

You can easily check these issues by also outputting the index of your array that you write to, in your code you would write two times to the same index of the array.

**Edit:** there was no need to alloc more chars `row*col+row` was correct, but you need (col+1) inside the loop.

**Edit 2** better to use (col+1) also in allocating the array, now it only worked because row = col.

Comment: Did you get the output as the above???
And I'm not overwriting the same index of the array, because the variable j is initialized again as it is declared outside the loops.

Comment: Yes I get the correct output, and yes your value is overwritten in the beginning of the next for loop, `i+col+j` has with your code the values: 0:a 1:a 2:\n 2:a 3:a 4:\n , so the first \n is overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding your values. use the code below

```
    int row, col;
        row = col = 2;
        int j;
        char[] ch = new char[row * col + row];
        for (int i = 0; i < ch.Length; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                ch[i + j] = 'a';
                //Console.Write(ch[ i * col + j ]);
            }
            ch[i + j] = '\n';
            i = i  + j;               
            //ch[i * col + (j+1)] = '\n';
            //Console.Write(ch[ i * col + j ]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Character Array:");
        foreach (char c in ch)
        {
            Console.Write(c);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is re-assigning the value to same index

Try below code:

```
int row, col;
     row = col = 2;
     int j;
     char[] ch = new char[ row * col + row ];
     for( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) {
        for( j = 0; j < 2; j++ ) {
           ch[ i * col + (j+i) ] = 'a';
           //Console.Write(ch[ i * col + j ]);
        }
        ch[ i * col + (j+i) ] = '\n';
        //Console.Write(ch[ i * col + j ]);
     }
     Console.WriteLine("Character Array:");
     foreach( char c in ch ) {
        Console.Write(c);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
int col = 3;
```

You need to allow for one more column to store you value of `\n`.